# Converting GMT to Local time format in android

Tags: android, datetime-format

I am new to android developer. I convert the GMT to local mobile time.  I got am /pm issues in this code. After 6'o clock evening time . I got am in conversion.
sorry for my English. Advance thanks for help.

```
    public String formatDate(String s)
    {
        String outputText=null;
        try {
//            Tue May 21 14:32:00 GMT 2012
            String inputText =s;
            SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm 'GMT'", Locale.US);
            inputFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));


            if(android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat(CalloutAvalibality.this))
            {

                SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yy HH:mm");
                // Adjust locale and zone appropriately
                Date date = inputFormat.parse(inputText);


                outputText= outputFormat.format(date)+" "+"Hrs";
                System.out.println(outputText);

            }
            else
            {
                SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a");

                // Adjust locale and zone appropriately
                Date date = inputFormat.parse(inputText);
                outputText= outputFormat.format(date);

//                outputText=outputText.replace("AM","am");
//                outputText=outputText.replace("PM","pm");
                System.out.println(outputText);
            }


        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return outputText;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

datefomater.format() will return you a string which is converted to timezone you initially set with the formatter object.

datefomater.parse() will return you a Date object which is in you local timezone

The Date object will set to default timezone

```
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Chicago");
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
formatter.setTimeZone(timeZone);

String result = formatter.format(YOUR_DATE_OBJECT);
```